# Html file that displays json

Tags: html, json

im trying to make a html file that displays the contents of the following json

list.json

```
{
"NAME1": {
    "a": "16",
    "b": "8",
    "Access": "CONST",
},
"NAME2": {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "82,
    "Access": "RO"
}etc.}
```

"NAME1" is the name of the entry and is variable. There can be x entrys
Structure is always the same -> each entry always has "a", "b" and "access"

Display should then look sth. like this

```
NAME1:
 a: 16
 b: 8
 Access: CONST

NAME2:
 a:
 b:
```

ive searched for solutions but none of them seem to work for me and i really have no clue regarding html.

It would also be very nice if you also had some way of searching for "NAME1" and then only this entry shows

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated solution.
Define your path or ways to get the variable

In your <your_path>.js:

```
const foo = {...} // the json object you mentioned
```

In your index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p id="text"></p>

</body>

<script src="<your_path>.js"></script>
<script>

    let variable_you_like = <your variable you like>

    let a = foo[variable_you_like].a;
    let b = foo[variable_you_like].b;
    let access = foo[variable_you_like].Access;

    document.getElementById('text').innerText = `${variable_you_like}: \n ${a} \n ${b} \n ${access}`;
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow that was fast, couple of issues tho

1. the json is its own file and not inside the html
2. the "NAME1" is a variable, we dont know how its name is. Theres an infinite number of entrys, but "a", "b" and "access" are always there
3. its shows as {"a":"16","b":"8","Access":"CONST"}. The Name is missing

Comment: I assume you save a json as another file and you can add a script with src to access the json object. Then, define your variable that you want with string or a method you like. Get each property and then display them as a string literals. Hope this can address you problem.